# Python alternative to Java DataFlow Streaming code

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, dataflow

I have the following java code snippet which polls the gcs bucket for the arrival of new files. This is the code that I am using for my streaming pipeline, which would further load the data after applying some transformations into some destination.

```
PCollection<String> pcollection = pipeline.apply("Read From streaming source",
                TextIO.read().from("gs://abc/xyz")
                        .watchForNewFiles(Duration.standardSeconds(10), Watch.Growth.never()));
```

but for a particular use case I need to achieve the same thing using python, for which I am unable to find the required libraries, also all the implementations for the streaming pipelines in python are for PubSub. Running the python pipeline with `streaming=true` doesn't solve any purpose as the code exits after completion and doesn't wait for new files. Can someone suggest a way to proceed?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wrt _"Running the python pipeline with streaming=true doesn't solve any purpose"_ - show your code. This isn't a code conversion service and seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, etc. are offtopic for this site. Have you checked the [Python gcp docs](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `MatchContinuously` [(doc)](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.33.0/apache_beam.io.fileio.html?highlight=matchall#apache_beam.io.fileio.MatchContinuously), which was added in this [Pull Request](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/15106).

Edit:

Given that I saw you had some issues with the PTransform (I think you deleted the comments), I am going to add a sample code:

```
(p | MatchContinuously("gs://apache-beam-samples/shakespeare/*", interval=10.0)
   | Map(lambda x: x.path)
   | ReadAllFromText()
   | Map(lambda x: logging.info(x))
)
```